# Rotational matrix problem?

Tags: transformation, rotations, applications

In the problem yo-yo is made of two identical cylinders of radius $R$, thickness $h$ and mass $M$, and the yo-yo is let go.

In order to define the position of the yo-yo, I need as position vector and a rotation matrix.

In the example of asteroid problem in space when we find the Euler's equation of solid body motion. The  $r$ is in $R^3$ and transformation $\phi$ is  $\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
0&{ - {x_3}}&{{x_2}}\\
{{x_3}}&0&{ - {x_1}}\\
{ - {x_2}}&{{x_1}}&0
\end{array}} \right)$.
The asteroid problem has 6 degrees of freedom.

**Here comes my problem**, If I assume yo-yo also rotate as the asteroid example, 
the problem has only two degrees of freedom, so I assign the origin of system in the center of yo-yo's first position, the position vector is just in $R^1$, which measures the length the yo-yo has gone from the original positon.
The rotation of the yo-yo is just rotation around the one-point. So is it OK to just follow the asteroid problem? Is there anything I need to change?

Comment: Your matrix (with zeros on the diagonal) is not a rotation matrix.  If $v=(x_1, x_2, x_3)$, the matrix you've given could be used to compute a cross product with $v$.

Comment: What do you mean by the normal problem? The cross product matrix is used when you want to describe rotation w.r.t an axis though. In your case do you assume the yoyo to rotate in a plane? The matrix you gave is a rotation fixing $z$-axis.

Comment: @Muphrid You are right. It is not rotation matrix. If I want to solve the yo-yo problem using the same method as the asteroid problem using the rotation matrix. Can I just copy the method in space to yo-yo problem? Is there anything I need to change?

Comment: @Qidi I mean the example of asteroid in space, when finding the Euler equation of solid body motion. Sorry about that.

Comment: @Qidi Yes. I assume yo-yo rotate in the plane. Can I just copy the method in the asteroid example in $R^3$? Is there anything I need to change?